# React Suspense best practice

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am working on adding some progress indicators to my React web application.

So far I have been using the following as a basis.
[react-suspense-data-fetching](https://blog.logrocket.com/react-suspense-data-fetching/).

```js
export interface ISuspender<T> {
    read(): T;
}

const createSuspender = <T,>(promise: Promise<T>): ISuspender<T> => {
    let status: string = 'pending';
    let response: T;

    const suspender: Promise<void> = promise.then(
        (result) => {
            status = "susccess";
            response = result;
        },
        (error) => {
            status = "error";
            response = error;
        }
    );
    const read = (): T => {
        switch (status) {
            case 'pending':
                throw suspender;
            case 'error':
                throw response;
            default:
                return response;
        }
    }
    return { read }
}

const getSetsSuspender: ISuspender<Scry.Set[]> = createSuspender(Scry.Sets.all());

export const MtgSetList: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
    const sets: Scry.Set[] = getSetsSuspender.read();

    return (
        <SetList sets={sets} />
    )
}
```

It works but not as well as I would like it to. For starters the data returned is not stored in state so I am unable to interact with it and add filtering capabilities.

I am also not a huge fan of how the suspender needs to be declared outside of the component.

Ideally I would like to write the MtgSetList like this

```js
export const MtgSetList: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
    const getSetsSuspender: ISuspender<Scry.Set[]> = createSuspender(Scry.Sets.all());
    const [sets, setSets] = React.useState<Scry.Set[]>();

    useEffect(() => {        
        setSets(getSetsSuspender.read());
    }, [getSetsSuspender]);
   
    return (
        <SetList sets={sets} />
    )
}
```

Any and all advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Move getSetsSuspender inside a useEffect hook. Then, use getSetsSuspender.read() to retrieve the data and set the state using setSets.

```
export const MtgSetList: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
    const [sets, setSets] = React.useState<Scry.Set[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getSetsSuspender: ISuspender<Scry.Set[]> = createSuspender(Scry.Sets.all());

        try {
            const fetchedSets = getSetsSuspender.read();
            setSets(fetchedSets);
        } catch (error) {
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <SetList sets={sets} />
    );
}
```

Comment: With your suggestion I was able to get it to build. However the loading indicator never loads and the data is never retrieved.

It almost looks as is the Suspense boundary is not getting the thrown Promise. I wonder if its because it was thrown from within a useEffect.

Answer (score 0):

While still not perfect I have gotten it somewhat working by creating the suspender instance outside of the component. That was causing some weird refreshing behavior. So I added a check to see if I needed to retrieve the data or not.

```js
const suspender = createSuspender(Scry.Sets.all());

export const MtgSetList: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
    const [sets, setSets] = React.useState<Scry.Set[]>();

    if(!sets){       
        const fetchedSets = suspender.read();
        setSets(fetchedSets);
    }   
    return (
        <SetList sets={sets} />
    )
}
```